# Clearing jest mocks between test not working

Tags: jestjs

If I run the below tests independently they both pass, If I run them together then the react screen that is used for the tests is the final screen of the second test. (I can reverse their order and its always the second test). Which will cause the first test to fail.

- Have only one test in file (Both Tests Pass)
- Have test A then test B (Test B will Pass and A will fail)
- Have test B then test A (Test A will pass and B will fail)

The mocks are interfering with the second tests, or react testing library is not clearing its render? Why is this happening?

Code:

```
import React from 'react'
import { render, screen } from '@testing-library/react'
import { UserProvider } from '../../../../src/providers/user'
import { useApi } from '../../../../src/providers/useApi'
import { useAuth } from '../../../../src/providers/authentication'

jest.mock('next/router', () => ({
  __esModule: true,
  useRouter: jest.fn(),
}))

jest.mock('../../../../src/providers/authentication', () => ({
  AuthContext: jest.fn(),
  useAuth: jest.fn(),
}))

jest.mock('../../../../src/providers/useApi', () => ({
  useApi: jest.fn(),
}))

afterEach(() => {
  jest.clearAllMocks();
});

describe('user provider', () => {
  describe('given: api returns no data', () => {
    ;(useAuth as jest.Mock).mockImplementation(() => {
      return { isAuthenticated: true }
    })
    ;(useApi as jest.Mock).mockReturnValue({ data: null })
    it('should: show loading screen', () => {
      render(<UserProvider />)
      const loadingElement = screen.getByTestId('loading-element')
      expect(loadingElement).not.toBeNull()
    })
  })

  describe('given: api returns data', () => {
    ;(useAuth as jest.Mock).mockImplementation(() => {
      return { isAuthenticated: true }
    })
    ;(useApi as jest.Mock).mockReturnValue({ data: { readUser: 'data' } })
    it('should: not show loading screen', () => {
      render(<UserProvider />)
      const loadingElement = screen.queryByTestId('loading-element')
      expect(loadingElement).toBeNull()
    })
  })
})
```

Comment: Why are you using describe inside describe? I recommend you to remove the first describe.

Comment: To subdivide the tests, I'm just showing 2 of 21 tests here, putting describes inside describes to subdivide is a very common practice and not the cause of the issue, it has no impact even when there removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was the mocks all needed to be modified inside the same block as react-testing-library's render.

(Moved the it() up to right after the preceding describe